# Initializing 2D arrray of Arraylist<Integer> type

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist

I need to use a N by N matrix, where each cell is of type Arraylist.
I declared a 2D array like below:

```
public static int N;
private static ArrayList<Integer>[][] matrix;
public MyConstructor() {
    matrix = new ArrayList[N][N];
}
```

But, it shows error.
How can I initialize that variable "matrix" inside a constructor ?

Comment: What is the error?  `N` is not declared. Also it should be `n`

Comment: Initializing a static variable (that therefor doesn't belong to any object) inside a constructor that creates an object looks like a code smell to me. Apart from that your problem is that Arrays need to be a specific size, so `N` needs to be a variable that at the time of the constructor has a specific numeric value (like `int N = 10;` for example). Initializing an Array undefined dimensions isn't possible.

Comment: What is the error? `N` is now declared but not instantiated (set to a value). Also it should be `n`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize a multi-dimensional array in one go in Java. First you have to initialize the outer dimension and then in a loop the inner dimension. This is because the inner dimension is not of a fixed size, you could have arrays of various lengths as inner dimension(s).

Also please don't mix generics and arrays in the way you did in your example, bad confusion is likely to happen.

And don't initialize static variables in the constructor, this should be either done in the declaration or in a static initialization block.

One of the ways to initialize a multi-dimensional array could be:

```java
Integer[][] matrix = new Integer[42][];
java.util.Arrays.setAll(i -> new Integer[123]);
```

(This examples uses the fixed dimension of 42 and 123 for the both dimensions.)

As the main question seems to be the initialization, I do not cover Generics, mixing with Lists, and static initialization here.

Answer (score 0):

Java will not allow you to create a generic array. Why don't you do it the other way round? Why not implement the matrix as an `ArrayList` of ArrayLists? I think that would be better.